# best way in setting up a j2ee dev and live enviornment

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

Hi guys i was wondering whats the best way/practise of setting up a j2ee project on a "live" machine that will be accessible worldwide when my web app is deployed and on a dev envrionment i.e. the pc i will use to write code.

i have two pc's at home. one is a server that is running certain services open to the world and another is my home pc where i do my usual personal stuff(play games, code, watch movies etc etc).

I have SVN installed and a repository setup on my server pc so i can easily access my projects from their and save/commit changes from my home pc or from my pc at work.

Now the app i am making uses tomcat and a MySQL database along with various different api's for hibernate, spring etc etc.

My question is whats the best way to set all this up on both machines and create different build targets for it?

should i just install tomcat, mysql and all the api's in both machines or any machine i wish to code on?

How do people from the corporate world manage this as im sure their is a ideal method of setting a dev environment that mimicks the live server and whenever you do a proper commit on the project, the live server gets updated with the latest build.

cheers in advance